# Sharepoint OnWorkflowItemChanged is out of control

Tags: sharepoint, events

I there,

I am working on a statemachine workflow. I have one state which listens to an `OnWorkflowItemChanged` event. The rest listens to `OnWorkflowModified` events. If I update an Item in another state than the state with the `OnWorkflowItemChanged` event the event is nevertheless caught by the `OnWorkflowItemChanged`. This happends at this time when the workflow comes back to the state owning the `OnWorkflowItemChanged` event.

What can I do to say the `OnWorkflowItemChanged` activity it should only listen to events trwon in its own state.

Thank you in advance Stefan

Answer (score 1):

I found a good Solution fior this Problem:

http://unclepaul84.blogspot.com/2007/12/disable-event-firing-in-sharepoint-when.html

For me this works fine.